# Installing virtualbox on linode

Tags: virtualbox, linode, vagrant

I've followed the VirtualBox installation guide found [here](http://dlc.sun.com.edgesuite.net/virtualbox/4.2.12/UserManual.pdf) and have switched my Linode kernel to use 2.6.32-47-generic-pae using this [guide](https://library.linode.com/custom-instances/pv-grub-howto#sph_ubuntu-10-04-lts-lucid), but I still keep getting the following error when I run `sudo /etc/init.d/vboxdrv setup`:

Starting VirtualBox kernel modules ...failed!
  (Running VirtualBox in a Xen environment is not supported)

Any ideas?

Comment: You can't run a virtual machine in a virtual machine. VirtualBox won't support it.

Comment: And if you want to run production virtual machines, VirtualBox should be nowhere on your list of things to install.

Comment: @tombull89 we need to go deeper!

Answer (score 3):

> Starting VirtualBox kernel modules ...failed! (Running VirtualBox in a Xen environment is not supported)

This seems fairly clear, your server is a Xen client and as such you can't run VirtualBox within it.

You need to get a VPS thats supports this environment or real hardware.

Answer (score 1):

Your Linode VPS is already a virtual machine (running under Xen).  You need a piece of physical hardware to run VirtualBox.